# How to invoke ondragstart and drop event manually javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

I have used html ondragstart and ondrop events.

```
  <div class="row height_380_div" id="target_div_id" ondragover="drag_over(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
       <div ondragstart="dragStart(event)" class="alert alert-warning col-lg-12 height_30_div node" draggable="true" id="call" name="Call" >
           <button class="close top_min_10 hidden call_btn" data-dismiss="alert" onclick="remove_btn(this)">
    &times;</button><p class="top_min_10">Call</p>
       </div>
 </div>
```

I want to drag and drop this dynamically on page load. Means for example, the div should be dragged to 100 px left and dropped there, which should be called dynamically when page loads and it should run on its own. How to do that?

Comment: Too broad. Please, reduce the question to a specific topic. We aren't a _make my code_ service.

Comment: Sorry! edited Now, please check whether it helps you to understand problem

Comment: Ok, I remove my close vote :)

Answer (score 1):

posted 6 year ago ((( ... anyways, if anyone needs it Ill leave it here ))

```
// add listenner to element
someElement.addEventListener('dragstart', () => '...do something');

// fire the custom event (I didn't check it in action, but it worked in my unit 
//tests so )))
const dragEvent = new Event('dragstart');
someElement.dispatchEvent(dragEvent);
```